# Can i use a DNS service to change my public ip?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, ip

My ip address is currently being banned by PlayStation Network. (My network is unreliable so as a result , i was probably flagged for DDoS or something, i really dont know). My ISP is of no help when they are called , and leaving my modem off for long periods of time does not always work to change my ip. The modem also does not allow me to edit the MAC address , so i basically cant change my public ip. I am asking if i sighn up for a service like SmartDNS , and link that to my ps4 , or any computer for that matter , would the apparent public ip for that machine change to that of the DNS server ?

Comment: Does your internet gateway provides you with a way of configuring a VPN or a proxy for the connection?

Comment: Use a proxy IP address if your PS supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wouldn't. You'd still have your public IP and a DNS entry just references to that IP.

As per "request" some elaboration on the problem at hand. What you're facing (probably) is an IP-based ban. Hence you're already trying to evade it by getting a different IP address. Depending on your kind of internet connection (DSL, Cable etc.) there are different methods to acquire a new IP. Generally it's mapped to your "user" by your ISP.

For DSL it's usually sufficient to reconnect, if you haven't booked a static IP. For a cable you might have to reset your connection which is usually done by disconnecting your modem and waiting for your DHCP lease to expire. The configuration of the lease duration depends on your ISP. Changeing your MAC address is usually not support (at least around here) as DOCSIS uses the MAC address to identify your modem and apply a configuration to it to get you connected to the network.

Now what you're trying to do, is to use a DNS entry to kind of mask your real IP. But this won't work as a DNS entry is just a pointer to an IP and most dynamic DNS providers use a client to dynamically point the DNS entry to your (banned) IP and a such you won't gain anything by it.

Get in contact with your ISP and ask them about the time it takes for the lease to expire (unlikely they know/will answer). They will most likely tell you (again) to disconnect the device and wait for say half an hour. After that reconnect and check what public IP you got and compare it to your current want. If you don't know how to lookup your internet IP use a site like [google](https://www.google.de/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=what+is+my+ip) or [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/). If you're still not able to get a new/different IP you could consider getting some kind of VPN which would hide your actual IP address. The downside being that you're usually not allowed to use them and it might get you banned again, possibly your account and not your IP. In addition the setup (most likely) isn't going to be all that easy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/568732)

Comment: Why don't you think it answers the question?

Comment: @Burgi it perfectly answers the question. The question is whenever or not a DNS entry would change anything about his IP based ban on PSN and it doesn't. As a DNS entry doesn't change the IP. So instead of giving a confusing text block maybe elaborate why you think this answer is insufficient?

Comment: @Seth: on these forums, you need to provide the most complete answers you can. Think of it as if the OP has zero knowledge and you have to explain (mostly) everything. It's good for general comprehension of the question, for you too as it enables you to learn by teaching, and also for long-term searches.

Comment: Hrm, thanks for pointing that out. I guess my edit should provide some more context in that case. I feel like an explanation about a VPN and/or proxy would go a bit overboard, even if it might be a way to evade the ban.